# Dockerfile accept multiple args and choose an action

Tags: docker

I have a python image that launches a web app and I'm wondering if it's possible to run pytest from container - I would like to choose if I want to run the app or run the tests.

Is possible?

My dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

COPY ./ ./x
WORKDIR ./x
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:5000", "--log-level=info", "app:app"]
```

Is possible to run something like `docker run x --someargumenttolaunchtests`?

Comment: (What happens if you run the exact `docker run` command you're suggesting?)

Answer (score 1):

You can set an ARGS value in your dockerfile which is an argument that you provided during build time. If you want to provide an arguement in run time, you can set an environment variable via docker run -e some_environment.

Then, you can, with a bash script, choose what you want to run. So your bash script provides your if some_eivonrment = ? then etc. You would have to make this bash script prior to run time and either COPY it to your dockerfile or bind it on run time.

So here is an example of a bash script.

```
#!bin/bash

ENVIRONMENT=$(export some_environment)

if("$ENVIRONMENT" = "test") ; then
   python run_test.py
else
   python main.py
fi
```

Before I forget, you need to set the permissions for this bash script.

So in your dockerfile:

```
COPY ./bash_script.sh /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod u+x bash_script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can completely override the entrypoint script and avoid `gunicorn`. Use something like:

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash myimagename pytest
```